# How to run an if statement asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The following code is a long, branched if-statement. When I use node to run it, the console ouput is `undefined` (this behaviour is also replicated in the code snippet below). So essentially, the full if-statement isn't getting executed, and (I assume) the synchronous nature of javascript causes the function to end before the if-statement is executed in its totality. How can I wait for the if-statement to run before the function ends (maybe async-await or a promise)?

The code is as follows (it's a DIY date-validator that ensures dates are in the form DD/MM/YYYY and that the date is today's date or in the future):

```js
function validDate(input){
    let monthLengths = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    if (input[2] !== "/" || input[5] !== "/"){
        return false;
    } else if (!Number.isInteger(+input[0]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[1]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[3]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[4]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[6]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[7]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[8]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[9])){
        return false;
    } else if (input.length !== 10){
        return false;
    } else if (input.substr(3, 2) === "02"){
        // check if leap year
        if (+input.substr(0, 2) > 29){
            return false;
        } else if (input.substr(0, 2) === "29" && +input.substr(6, 4)%4 != 0){
            return false;
        }
    } else if (+input.substr(0, 2) > monthLengths[+input.substr(3, 2) - 1]){
        return false;
    } else if (Date.now() - Date.now()%86400000 - 86400000/3 > Date.parse(input.substr(3, 2) + "/" + input.substr(0, 2) + "/" + input.substr(6, 4))){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
console.log(validDate("02/02/2022"))
```

Comment: Nothing in this code is asynchronous. I think the problem is in the nested if in the middle - it does not have a `return true` branch and it does not come back to the main if chain.

Comment: By the way, a year that can be divided by 100 but not by 400 is not a leap year even though it can be divided by 4.

Comment: @Noam, your comment was correct. Could you format that as an answer, so that I can mark it as solved please

Comment: A real simple way would be to use `<input type="date">`, but if you want to stick to the text type, it would be much easier to split the value by `/`, and check the parts separately.

Comment: @AnOn1m1ty, it's okay :) . I'm pretty new here, but from what I recollect little debug mistakes are encouraged to come on comments and not on answers, since they have usually no use for other people. Also there is already such an answer.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks so much tho! Also, if you're talking about @Aooiu's answer, it doesn't work. I had to modify it more. Because as soon as you put an else, that stops the rest of the if chain from executing

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validDate(input){
  let monthLengths = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

  if (input.substr(3, 2) === "02"){
    // check if leap year
    if (+input.substr(0, 2) > 29){
        return false;
    } else if (input.substr(0, 2) === "29" && +input.substr(6, 4) % 4 != 0){
        return false;
    } 
  } 

  if (input[2] !== "/" || input[5] !== "/"){
      return false;
  } else if (!Number.isInteger(+input[0]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[1]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[3]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[4]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[6]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[7]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[8]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[9])){
      return false;
  } else if (input.length !== 10){
      return false;
  } else if (+input.substr(0, 2) > monthLengths[+input.substr(3, 2) - 1]){
      return false;
  } else if (Date.now() - Date.now()%86400000 - 86400000/3 > Date.parse(input.substr(3, 2) + "/" + input.substr(0, 2) + "/" + input.substr(6, 4))){
      return false;
  } else {
      return true;
  }

}
console.log(validDate("02/02/2022"))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clean code.

There are a couple of things we can do to make this code work a bit better. There is no need for using the `else` keyword that much, if you are returning a value inside a `function` you are already making sure that all lines of code after the if statements are not going to be run.

With that being said we can make these changes:

```
function validDate(input){
    let monthLengths = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    if (input[2] !== "/" || input[5] !== "/") return false;
    if (!Number.isInteger(+input[0]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[1]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[3]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[4]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[6]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[7]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[8]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[9])) return false;
    if (input.length !== 10) return false;
    if (input.substr(3, 2) === "02") {
        // check if leap year
        if (+input.substr(0, 2) > 29) return false;
        if (input.substr(0, 2) === "29" && +input.substr(6, 4)%4 != 0) return false;

    }
    if (+input.substr(0, 2) > monthLengths[+input.substr(3, 2) - 1]) return false;
    if (Date.now() - Date.now()%86400000 - 86400000/3 > Date.parse(input.substr(3, 2) + "/" + input.substr(0, 2) + "/" + input.substr(6, 4))) return false;
    return true;
}
```

### Now it's easier to check edge cases.

Now that the code is a bit cleaner, we can simply add a `return true` statement where no `if` statement is accomplished inside the leap year block of code.

```
function validDate(input){
    let monthLengths = [31, 0, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    if (input[2] !== "/" || input[5] !== "/") return false;
    if (!Number.isInteger(+input[0]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[1]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[3]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[4]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[6]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[7]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[8]) || !Number.isInteger(+input[9])) return false;
    if (input.length !== 10) return false;
    if (input.substr(3, 2) === "02") {
        // check if leap year
        if (+input.substr(0, 2) > 29) return false;
        if (input.substr(0, 2) === "29" && +input.substr(6, 4)%4 != 0) return false;
        return true; // <----- This line we need to add.
    }
    if (+input.substr(0, 2) > monthLengths[+input.substr(3, 2) - 1]) return false;
    if (Date.now() - Date.now()%86400000 - 86400000/3 > Date.parse(input.substr(3, 2) + "/" + input.substr(0, 2) + "/" + input.substr(6, 4))) return false;
    return true;
}
```

### Another solution (shorter)

We can take advantage of the `Date` object that JS has already built in. I suggest this next function:

```
const validDate = (input) => {
  if (input.length !== 10) return false;
  const [ day, month, year ] = input.split("/");
  if(day.length !== 2 || month.length !== 2 || year.length !== 4) return false;
  if(!day || !month || !year || isNaN(+day)|| isNaN(+month)|| isNaN(+year)) return false;
  const now = new Date(), inputDate = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day, 23, 59, 59);
  return inputDate >= now;
}

validDate("02/02/2022");
```

Comment: With your last code snippet, `validDate("2/220/2022")` returns `true`

Comment: You are right sir. I'll fix it.

Comment: It is fixed now. We just needed to add a new required length for the three variables: `if(day.length !== 2 || month.length !== 2 || year.length !== 4) return false;`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to move everything into switch statement. Would be needer and will cause no your explained problems.

[Switch statement description](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: A switch statement can only compare a single value to a set of values, it cannot account for this type of conditions.